# Xcode: TabBar not showing in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Interface Builder: I have a `TabBarController` connected to three different scenes. Every scene starts with a `NavigationController` and then has some different `ViewControllers`.

The problem now is, that the Interface Builder is not longer showing the `TabBars` in the different scenes, expect in the `TabBarController`. I can still access the `TabBarItems` in the Document Outline and the app runs as expected, but it confuses me.

Every scene is refactored to its own Storyboard, in case that matters.

Thanks in advance for any hint!

**Edit**: I hope these pictures make the issue more clear. There should be a TabBar (with a TabBarItem) in the second picture, but there isn't one.

[image]
[image]

Comment: it s difficult to say without looking at it. Make sure that it is not hidden. Does the screen shows first view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell IB to include a tab bar in your View Controller by selecting it and then selecting `Opaque Tab Bar` in the `Bottom Bar` dropdown, under `Simulated Metrics`.

[image: Simulated Metrics in Xcode]