# Why does "inferred" setting in Interface Builder not work?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

I was using interface builder to create a storyboard for my project. I had a few problems that felt like Xcode bugs, so I restarted xCode. The bugs all felt like the same thing.

The problem was that all my tab bar icons were not showing up in the `UITabViewController`'s child views. They were, however showing up in the actual `UITabView`. The same thing was happening with the navigation bars in navigation controllers.

I looked this up and found this stack overflow post: [Xcode: TabBar not showing in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192733/xcode-tabbar-not-showing-in-interface-builder). This fixed my problem and I can now see tab bars and navigation bars, but I don't understand why it won't work when it is on inferred, it used to work.

Here is an image:
[image: Simulated Metrics in xCode].

My question is why I have to set "Bottom Bar" to "Translucent Tab Bar" to get it to work, rather than "inferred".

Note: I have already tried cleaning the project and restarting xCode. If answers include code, I would prefer Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue in xCode 7.3.1. Here I have attached some screenshots.

1. These project is created in xCode 7.2. You can see here also `inferred` is worked fine and you can see `tabor`.

[image]

1. These project is created in xCode 7.3.1 Here at first I have `tabbar` with dark gray color by default when I add `tabbar`.

[image]

Then I set `translucent` and again I set `inferred`, it can be see clearly.

[image]

Comment: Well, if it is an issue in Xcode 7.3 I guess I'll just have to wait. However, I remember it used to work and I have never updated Xcode.